# Handle SwiftUI and CoreLocation with MVVM-Pattern

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, swiftui, core-location

i am trying to implement **SwiftUI** and **CoreLocation** with the **MVVM-Pattern**. My `LocationManager` as Helper works fine. But how I can change the properties of my `LocationViewModel`? I am implemented my `@ObservedObject` of the `LocationManager` in `LocationViewModel`. Here is my problem.

I don't have a idea to implement properties they change on the fly. Nothing is changed in my LocationView. By pressing a Button anything works fine one time. But the `LocationViewModel` must change there properties on every change of the `LocationManager`.

In summary I would like to display the current user position.

```
// Location Manager as Helper

import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func geoCode(with location: CLLocation) {

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.placemark = placemark?.first
            }
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.location = location
            self.geoCode(with: location)
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

```
// Location Model

import Foundation
import CoreLocation

struct Location {
    var location: CLLocation = CLLocation()
    var placemark: CLPlacemark = CLPlacemark()
}
```

```
// Location View Model

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()

    @Published var location: Location

    init() {
        self.location = Location()
    }
}
```

```
// Location View

import SwiftUI

struct LocationView: View {

    @ObservedObject var locationViewModel: LocationViewModel = LocationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Latitude: \(self.locationViewModel.location.location.coordinate.latitude.description)")
            Text("Longitude: \(self.locationViewModel.location.location.coordinate.longitude.description)")
        }
    }
}

struct LocationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LocationView()
    }
}
```

**Update**

Now, I have set up my **MapView**.

But how I can receive the data of my `LocationManager`? The `didUpdateLocations` method is working in `LocationManager`.

All what I am trying to do goes wrong. I would like to set the region on my `MapView` based on the current user location. In UIKit it was very simple, but in SwiftUI it is freaky.

```
// Map View

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

        var parent: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.parent = control
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Jurie, did you find approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2**

Use instead `StateObject` in this case

```
struct LocationView: View {

    @StateObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()
    ...
```

**SwiftUI 1**

Actually `LocationViewModel` is redundant here. As your `LocationManager` is a `ObservableObject` you can use it directly in your view, as below:

```
struct LocationView: View {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Latitude: \(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude.description)")
            Text("Longitude: \(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude.description)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works fine. Does this implementation conform to the MVVM pattern? I'm trying to understand this pattern at SwiftUI. However, in this case it is not easy to use.

Comment: This is an example of how you do MVVM without VM. MVVM is not about having an object called ViewModel, which has no SDK or language binding support whatsoever.

Comment: I think this is more conformant with MVVM https://mobileinvader.com/corelocation-in-swiftui-mvvm-unit-tests/