# Where to put delegates of CLLocationManager using Swift UI?

Tags: swiftui, cllocationmanager, swift5, geofencing

I've been on and off Swift for the years so, sorry if I'm doing something stupid, the Swift UI thing isn't helping my confusion either. I have the code I'm working with at the bottom.

So I'm making a Geofencing app using SwiftUI, I've got the basics up and running but still have a bit to go with it,

- I have the Geofencing coordinates and stuff inside the UserData environment variable, which I get off a json elsewhere.
- Have a SwiftUI object that has a map out with the current position and initializes a CLLocationManager to deal with geofencing.

I'm trying to implement the delegate on the same file by

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

in the setupManager(),

but it will cause

```
Cannot assign value of type 'GeofencingView' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'
```

The lack of SwiftUI specific information online seems to be causing the most confusion for me at the moment, I think what I should do is,

1. create a customized NsObject that handles the delegates, but in that case I'm not sure how to pass the @EnviromentObject
2. Find out how to put the delegates on the UIViewRepresentable object.

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct GeofencingView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var notification = LocalNotificationManager()

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func setupManager() {

      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        self.startGoefenceMonitoring()
    }


    func startGoefenceMonitoring() {

        print("MapListView::startGeofenceMonitoring")



        for landmark in self.userData.landmarks {

            let moniteringCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(landmark.locationCoordinate.longitude, landmark.locationCoordinate.latitude)
            let moniteringRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: moniteringCordinate, radius: 20.0, identifier: "\(landmark.id)" )
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: moniteringRegion)

        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {

      setupManager()
      let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      let count = self.userData.landmarks.count
      var annotationArray: [MKAnnotation] = []
      var num:Int = 0


      mapView.showsUserLocation = true
      mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow        

      return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }
}

struct GeofencingView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GeofencingView()
            .environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIViewRepresentable` has class `Coordinator` pattern, which can be used as delegate. Please see topic [Handle SwiftUI and CoreLocation with MVVM-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620573/handle-swiftui-and-corelocation-with-mvvm-pattern) for example of usage.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I wanted.