# Using startUpdatingLocation() and stopUpdatingLocation() to activate/deactivate location updates in specific Views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location, cllocationmanager

Based on some code examples from stackoverflow I created a class for location service. The location service is started immediately when the app starts, indicated by the navigation symbol in the upper system bar. My app needs the location service in specific views only, so I would like to activate/deactivate the location service on specific events. This could reduce energy consumption and improve customers confidence, that location service is used only when needed.

First I defined a class LocationViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation
import CoreMotion

class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject
{

    @Published var userLatitude: Double = 0
    @Published var userLongitude: Double = 0
        
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    // I tried this to access the startUpdatingLocation() method, but it did not work
    func startUpdatingLocation()
    {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
        
}

extension LocationViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        
        userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        userLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

Next, in a specific LocationView, which is part of a NavigationView, I create a instance of LocationViewModel class:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LocationView : View
{
    // some say, that a @StateObject is preferred over @ObservedObject, see:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620573/handle-swiftui-and-corelocation-with-mvvm-pattern
    @ObservedObject var locationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Latitude: \(locationViewModel.userLatitude)")
            Text("Longitude: \(locationViewModel.userLongitude)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Location")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Why is the location service started when the app starts? The override init() method calls the startUpdatingLocation(), but the LocationView (defined as part of a NavigationView) is not shown on apps startup. Is this an effect of the NavigationView?
2. How can I access the self.locationManager's startUpdatingLocation() method from outside the instance? Is there any way to do that directly or is it necessary to create a specific wrapper method (as I already tried without success)? The LocationViewModel instance does not offer any methods (XCode says there are no completions).
3. How can I start/stop location updates (navigation symbol to disappear) when the specific view becomes visible/invisble? All code examples I found implemented permanent location updates.

Comment: You would be better off having a single instance of your location manager that you inject into the environment. You can then start updating location in an `.onAppear`

Comment: If your `LocationView` is the destination of a `NavigationLink`, its `init` method will be called when the nav link is shown on the screen. So any work you do in the `init` will be executed at that point.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. That answers my questions 1. and 3. @Paulw11: Can you describe what you mean with "inject into the environment". Declaring `locationViewModel` as a @ObservedObject makes the locationManager available over different Views. I'm fine with that, except not beeing able to start/stop location updates. I just cannot access the `locationViewModel` instance in a way to call locationManager's methods.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

My mistake was trying to call locationViewModel.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() method **before** the declaration of the views's body.

```
        .navigationTitle("Simulation")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear(perform: {locationViewModel.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()})
        .onDisappear(perform: {locationViewModel.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()})
```